# Will a Netty channel.write() or context.write() ever throw an exception?

Tags: netty

Do I need to expect any exceptions when calling any of these?

```
io.netty.channel.Channel.write(...)
io.netty.channel.Channel.flush(...)
io.netty.channel.Channel.writeAndFlush(...)
io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext.write(...)
io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(...)
```

It seems not. There are no checked exceptions, no throws are documented and I haven't seen any try/catch blocks in any example code. Yet I can't seem to find my assumption stated explicitly.

For example this does not throw any exceptions:

```
ChannelFuture closeFuture = channel.close();
closeFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception
    {
        channel.writeAndFlush(msg); // No exception when writing to closed channel
    });
```

Even though the channel is closed the written message is processed by all the downstream handlers as if the channel were open. Don't get me wrong; I'm perfectly happy with this behaviour! I can catch the `channelInactive` or `exceptionCaught` events, deal with them nicely and where I do care about the `write` I can listen for a successful future.

I just want someone to tell me that Netty really does let me write i/o stuff without endless exception handling! I'm using Netty 5.0.0.Alpha1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

it will not throw any exception but notify the returned ChannelFuture about any exceptions (or success) of the operation.